# \addtotoc starts new page

Tags: page-breaking

I have a section which I don't want to be numbered, but which I still want in the table of contents. So I have written

```
\addtotoc{section}{My section}
\section*{My section}
```

I have done the same thing for all the subsections in this section. The problem is just that the subsections end up at separate pages, creating a lot of empty space in my document. If I remove the `\addtotoc` macro then the problem disappears. The question is why `\addtotoc` automatically starts a new page and if this can be turned off?

Comment: Please edit your question and add a complete example that reproduces the problem. Without this it will be difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: I've found `\addtotoc` in the `ClemsonThesis` class and it has a very bizarre definition. If you're using that class, I strongly suggest *never* using that command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's quite difficult to answer without any example and the indication of the used class. I guess it's [`ClemsonThesis`](http://code.google.com/p/clemson-templates/source/browse/latex/ClemsonThesis.cls), where the `\addtotoc` command is defined as

```
\newcommand{\addtotoc}[2]{
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}
    #2 \clearpage
}
```

and the definition makes clear why a new page is started. It's quite difficult to understand what's the intended usage of this macro, but it's rather clear that it doesn't suit your needs.

If your sections are *never* numbered, you solve all problems by saying

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

in your document preamble and then using `\section{Section Title}` without any other code.

An occasional unnumbered section can be treated by

```
\phantomsection
\section*{My section}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{My section}
```

You might want to define a special command:

```
\newcommand{\usection}[1]{%
  \phantomsection
  \section*{#1}
  \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}
}
```

Comment: Ah, `\addcontentsline` was the command I really should have used! Thank you very much! :)